# More complex auto-correct features

Tags: microsoft-word

I am implementing a style guide. In it, it says that the € must always come before the number.

e.g. 8€ is wrong, €8 is right.

or that the GB must always have a space between itself and the quantity

e.g. 15GB is wrong, 15 GB is right.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this with auto-correct? It would be immensely useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For GB you could use autocorrect by adding 10 variations:

0GB => 0 GB
...
9GB => 9 GB